# Where to find information of Django internals and design

Tags: django, internals

where can I find information of Django internals? more updated then that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkwZ1jG3XgA ?

It is a very good tutorial, but it is almost 20 years old. In Django, I cannot find anything for learning about  the internals design decision and architecture, except the old video I mentioned and this very short presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Famf5Sc_jg&ab_channel=EuroPythonConference

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find the updated detailed information about Django on it official [documentation site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/), if  you want to dig deeper you can go through the [source code](https://github.com/django/django) of Django which is available in GitHub.

Comment: I'm asking for some preliminary steps. In theory, I can read every program source code, but a book, course or tutorial is a better introduction  @sumithran

Comment: I'm afraid we are not allowed to answer this question, [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417480/6562458)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. for django internals it is the official link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/

django use meta programming a lot in its ORM & Form & Admin.

to understand django public API's you need to first understand meta programming & meta class in django.

For understanding how to use the django ORM properly you can check this playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQF6pln3Gog&list=PLOLrQ9Pn6cazjoDEnwzcdWWf4SNS0QZml .

For understanding django models internal meta API this video is a good start, though it might seem too advance at first:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgM0qmpHDiE

I will be adding more relevant links to my answer.

Also for  advance level deep understanding of the internals of django components this conference website has slides and videos both to increase your depth in django https://djangounderthehood.com/

And all the videos can be found in this link https://www.youtube.com/@djangounderthehood420/videos

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome. I lost some more docs and refs which I will try to include in future